# What does "a month" mean in "I see that you take quite a few business trips a month."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Look at [this American conversation](http://www.talkenglish.com/conversation/practice/frequent-flier-miles)

> Isabel: Hi Vicky, this is Isabel. I'm the company's travel coordinator.
>   Vicky: Hi Isabel. Is there a problem?
>   Isabel: No. I see that you take quite a few business trips a month.
>   Vicky: Yes, I do.
>   Isabel: I noticed that you are not signed up for frequent flier miles.
>   Vicky: No, I haven't signed up yet.
>   Isabel: Please sign up before your next trip. You can earn miles and get a free trip anywhere in the country.
>   Vicky: I didn't know that.
>   Isabel: It's easy to sign up. You can do it online.
>   Vicky: I will do that today since I have another business trip at the end of the week.

What does "**a month**" mean in "**I see that you take quite a few business trips a month.**"?

I know that American people often omit prepositions before Mondays, mornings.

Example "*Do you work Saturdays?*"="*Do you work on Saturdays?*"

I am not sure whether they omit "**in**" in "**in a month**".

Comment: In this case, "a month" means "per month", an observation that she's traveling often.

Comment: That isn't  an omission of the preposition before "Mondays, mornings". It is a relic of a genitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does "a month" mean in "I see that you take quite a few business trips a month."

In this case **a month** refers to the frequency of trips taken **each** month.

You can also say **per** month which means the same thing.

Also, if you use **each month**, **a month** or **per month** then I think that it is implied, but not stated, that a number of trips are made for several months in a year, or in succession.

I'm not sure that North Americans  omit the preposition **in**

Living in Canada, I can only say that I have only heard: a month, per month (less common), and each month.

It's possible that we use **in a month** to describe a quota,  as in the following sentence:

The factory has to produce fifty cars in a month to make a profit.

I hope that helps.

Comment: You mean "The factory has to produce fifty cars *within* a month to make a profit." ?

Comment: Generally good answer, but I think the "in a month" explanation misses the mark.  The quota you describe would be better stated as "per month". "A month", "per month" or "each month" refer to recurring past behavior, a monthly rate or frequency.  "In a month" would more likely refer to a one-time current or upcoming requirement.

Comment: I have long been under the impression that Canada _is_ in North America; have you really never heard anyone say _"Oh, I can't make it, I work Saturdays"_ or _"I worked six months on that project"_?